# Delete millions of pandas rows, w.r.t values in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy array (users_to_remove) consisting of user Ids to remove (75000 in that array) , and a pandas dataframe(orders) from which I want to remove rows that contain thoses Ids.

orders has about 35 million rows.

Here is how I currently proceed:

```
for i in users_to_remove:
    orders = orders[orders.user_id != i]
```

Its taking ages and still didnt finish. I have 8gb of ram and a quad core i5 with 3,2ghz.

Is there an efficient way to do this with pandas, should I use another language ? Or is my computer just to slow for this?

Thank you

Comment: Is either of  `users_to_remove` or `orders.user_id` sorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
orders = orders[~orders.user_id.isin(users_to_remove)]
```

Timings are similar (but I have only 4GB RAM, i5 2.5 GHz Win7):

```
np.random.seed(100)
N = 35000000

users_to_remove = np.random.randint(75000, size=N)
orders = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':np.random.randint(100000, size=N)})
print (orders.head())

In [54]: %timeit (orders[~orders.user_id.isin(users_to_remove)])
1 loop, best of 3: 16.9 s per loop

In [55]: %timeit (orders[~np.in1d(orders.user_id.values, users_to_remove)])
1 loop, best of 3: 14.6 s per loop
```